# Avoid SQL Cursor in this scenario

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2005, database-cursor

I have inherited a system which seemingly requires me to use a cursor or while loop.
Given the below tables, I would like to get the names of the attendees e.g

> Bill
> Bob
> Jane
> Jill
>
> **Attendees**
>   SourceTable|SourceTableId
> Boys |1
> Boys |2
> Girls |2
> Girls |1
>
> **Boys**
>   Id|FirstName
> 1 |Bill
> 2 |Bob
>
> **Girls**
>   Id|FirstName
> 1 |Jill
> 2 |Jane

Note, the system doesn't actually use Attendees,Boys & Girls but rather uses Contracts, Orders and other such entities etc but it was easier\simpler to represent in this form. 
There may be loads more lookup tables than just "boy" and "girl" so

Is there anyway I can achieve this by not using cursors or other row based operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this query should work:

```
SELECT FirstName
  FROM Attendees
  join Boys on id = SourceTableId
 WHERE SourceTable = 'Boys'
union all
SELECT FirstName
  FROM Attendees
  join Girls on id = SourceTableId
 WHERE SourceTable = 'Girls'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the problem space is a lot larger, so source table could be Boys,Girls,Cats,Dogs,Fish.... so a union would need hundreds of cases. Sorry should have made that clearer

Comment: @Dan Black: It's a union portion for each of the underlying tables, right? What is your concern with this approach - performance? How many of these tables are there actually, and how many records do they each contain?

Comment: There is 794 possible tables, so my concern would be the length and static nature of the code

Comment: O_O Could you use one table with a column named "type"? (you should)

Comment: I wish I could, unfortunatly it's a third party inherited system so schema changes are not an option, could create a new table populated with this data by a nightly ETL process, but that would be excessive, and would run with a slow cursor solution before that. hmmmm

Comment: @Dan Black, now you know why it is a SQL Antipattern to design this way. Sorry it's a third party vendor whose schema you can't change. There is no performant or simple solution to your problem. Union is your best bet. If you do it in a view at least you only have to do it once!

Answer (score 0):

A union is probably the only way you're going to do this, probably encapsulated in a view.  If you can get a list of the tables then you could write a code generator that generates the view.  If necessary put the view in a different database or schema on the same server if the vendor won't allow you to put it in the application DB.

Can you programatically identify the tables and columns you need or get a list from somewhere?